# In Java, what is the difference between "var = 3;" and "this.var = 3;"?

Tags: java

Is the only purpose of this.var to distinguish from outside variable names that might conflict?

Comment: Basically, yes.  The `this` keyword can be used for other things, but in the use-case you are describing, that is its sole purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, this chances occurs when you are shadowing. Here's an example of shadowing.

```
public class YourClass
{

       private int var;

}
```

It happens that you have this method:

```
public void yourMethod(int var)
{

       this.var = var; // Shadowing

}
```

'this.var' happens to be your instance variable and is declared below your class. While on the other hand, in my example, var was a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Using `this` explicitly indicates the instance `var` as opposed to a constructor/method variable or parameter of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

One use case is:

If your method/constructor parameter also named as `var` and you want to access instance variable in that method, then you may need to explicitly tell `this.var` to use instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you write a constructor the names of the variables that you are passing on as arguments, might have the same name as the instance variables you declared within your methods. So this.var refers to the actual instance variable.